# Close Boxy when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, boxy

How do I close a Boxy dialog when clicked out-side the Boxy container?

Comment: I see no inbuilt functionality for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// jQuery 1.4
$(".boxy-modal-blackout").live("click", function(){
  Boxy.get($("body > table.boxy-wrapper").find(".boxy-content")).hide();
});
```